# I have a one-track mind, Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> *I don't know when will it end,
>
>   this battle I cannot comprehend.*
>   *Now I am helpless in the enemies thrall,*
>   *forced to watch my allies fall.*
>
> *I know I am not as capable,*
>   *since I have a one-track mind.*
>   *But I am driven and loyal,*
>   *equipped with unlimited potential.*
>
> *Somehow I know I'll be given a chance,*
>   *to be once again under your command.*
>   *I will reach deep within the enemy's end,*
>   *This time for sure I shall transcend!*

**Hint 1:**

> I only get side-tracked when I meet an enemy

Comment: are you a train?

Comment: @JonMark Perry That depends on how you think I am a train :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Piecing together the queenly clues, I'm thinking, after a look nigh towards the hint that you may take a crooked path, my stab is hopefully a

> pawn

I don't know when will it end, this battle I cannot comprehend.

> You are only a pawn in the game and it is difficult to know when a chess game is going to end.

Now I am helpless in the enemies thrall, forced to watch my allies fall.

> Obstructed by an enemy piece, cannot move - only look on when your side's pieces are taken.

I know I am not as capable, since I have a one-track mind.

> You can only move straight forward, unlike other pieces. 
>  The hint is the exception - a great fit by Lawrence's answer before this - you can move one diagonal forward when taking the enemy.

But I am driven and loyal, equipped with unlimited potential.

> You are driven to go forward, often sacrificing yourself for your side's benefit or protecting other pieces. You have unlimited potential as, if promoted, you may change into any other piece.

Somehow I know I'll be given a chance, to be once again under your command.
I will reach deep within the enemy's end, This time for sure I shall transcend!

> You (hope) you will reach the last rank, become active again and change into say a Queen.

Comment: Perfectly answered! +1

Answer (score 4):

You might be describing a

> **bowling ball**. The bowler is its 'enemy' and the bowling pins are its 'allies'.

First stanza:

> The ball doesn't know exactly when the game will end because the game may be extended due to strikes. It's 'helpless' because the bowler has control; its 'allies' fall when the ball strikes them, or when they rebound against each other.

Second stanza:

> The ball has a 'one-track mind' because it is constrained by bowling lanes. But it is 'driven' by the bowler and absolutely follows the laws of physics upon release. It can *potentially* be used over and over again.

Third stanza:

> After each bowl, the ball returns to the bowler, ready to be sent down the lane again ('once again under your command'). It reaches deep beneath the lanes in the course of being returned to the bowler. It emerges (*transcend*?) to wait with the rest of the returned balls.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect a different answer that almost matches all the clues. +1! It is not the correct answer though.

Comment: @JFox It's fun to see similarities in things that are often thought of as quite distinct. By the way, the lane gutters can be argued to fit your Hint 1. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking you might be a

> Jousting horse

I don't know when will it end,
this battle I cannot comprehend.

> I can't imagine a horse would understand jousting, it's not a normal sort of battle

Now I am helpless in the enemies thrall,
forced to watch my allies fall.

> If the rider gets a solid hit from his opponent, he'll be unhorsed; the horse cannot help his rider

I know I am not as capable,
since I have a one-track mind.

> Unlike in a real cavalry battle, a joust requires horse and rider to follow a specific, straight-line path

But I am driven and loyal,
equipped with unlimited potential.

> Horses are loyal, intelligent creatures, and they do have the potential to win the jousting match given enough tries

Somehow I know I'll be given a chance,
to be once again under your command.

> The rider will only win a match if he has good command of his mount

I will reach deep within the enemy's end,
This time for sure I shall transcend!

> If the horse gets close enough to the opponent (enemy), and the rider gets his lance solidly in a chink of his opponent's armor, he will unhorse the opponent and win the match!

Hint 1: I only get side-tracked when I meet an enemy

> The horse will only deviate from his straight path if the force of the opponent's lance blow is great enough to push him off track